# SSL handshake failure when using Logstash

Tags: ssl

I am using [Logstash](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/), and it works on most machines I have running. But on some, I get this error:

```
Failed to tls handshake with x.x.x.x x509: certificate is valid for , not dns_name
```

I read on someones blog, that they fixed it like this:

> Turned out to be my self-gen cert ;-P   I created a new one, using
>   properly filled out openssl.cnf and a wildcard domain.

But they did not put the steps that they used to do the above. Could someone please tell me how to create a self signed certificate with wildcard domain? And what it means to properly fill out the `openssl.cnf`.

Comment: Properly filled out would be your information and its not something you want to publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting connections via hostname—instead of IP address—it seems from reading [up on the issue here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-forwarder/issues/230) that the problem is Logstash now requires the SSL certificate for the host to have a CN (common name) set as well as generating the SSL *without* the `-batch` flag in place:

> Figured out the issue - looks like you need to generate the SSL
>   certificate differently now. It must include the 'common name' (i.e.
>   your servers hostname). In my case, I just dropped the `-batch` flag
>   when generating the certificate causing openssl to ask me for the
>   hostname.

The command would be something like this from the command line of any machine with OpenSSL installed:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout logstash-forwarder.key -out logstash-forwarder.crt
```

The `logstash-forwarder.key` and `logstash-forwarder.crt` can be changed to match your hostname if you wish.  When you run that command you will see something like this:

```
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.............................................+++
..........+++
unable to write 'random state'
writing new private key to 'logstash-forwarder.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:New York
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Brooklyn
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Some Company
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:my_hostname.local
Email Address []:
```

And what I entered for this example was as follows; the most important item is the “Common Name” (CN)

- **Country Name:** US
- **State or Province Name:** New York
- **Locality Name:** Brooklyn
- **Organization Name:** Some Company
- **Organizational Unit Name:** [I left this blank on purpose.]
- **Common Name:** my_hostname.local
- **Email Address:** [I left this blank on purpose.]

I personally like entering the country name, state & locality name since it helps me sort through these things, but those are really just icing on the cake. The “cake” itself is the hostname: `my_hostname.local`.

Now that solution works for connections made via hostname. If the machine you have an issue with does not have a hostname, one should be setup. Or it should perhaps be set in the `/etc/hosts` file on the connecting machine to at least “trick” the setup to use a hostname.

A user on that issue report posted a nice script to create a self-signed certificate for IP address use which is [located here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-forwarder/issues/230#issuecomment-49776669), but there should be a way to handle that from the command line directly as well. And looking at this site it seems that the issue is how to configure SSL requests with `SubjectAltName` while using OpenSSL.

Comment: Worked, massive thanks. I read so much on this, I missed the line "I just dropped the '-batch' flag"